# In what scenarios Apache camel should be used with Rabbitmq

Tags: java, apache-camel, rabbitmq, message-queue

I am using rabbitmq, and can perform all the required functions like message routing according to bindings.

I have never used apache camel but have used rabbitmq.

My Question is what additional features with camel-rabbitmq provide that are not provided by rabbitmq alone.

Answer (score 6):

Camel is an implementation of [enterprise integration patterns](http://camel.apache.org/enterprise-integration-patterns.html) whereas RabbitMQ is a messaging architecture.

Camel provides an abstraction so that endpoints are swappable with a minimum of fuss. If you were to use camel-rabitmq you could easily swap to jms for instance, or perhaps write to a file instead (or aswell).

You can also add routers, filters etc etc to your channels.

Comment: So, can I assume biggest advantage is producer can produce messages and send them to rabbitmq, and using camel-rabbitmq I can write that message to a file/or any other end point, not necessarily a queue consumer.This is my understanding from you second sentence. Is it correct?

Comment: The biggest advantage is [decoupling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_(computer_programming)). With camel, the producer can write to an endpoint. The consumer can read from an endpoint. Via routing configuration you can choose rabbit-mq for the endpoints at runtime. For testing you might not use rabbitmq and instead use a file endpoint. For debugging you might add a logging interceptor to the channel etc etc.